# Find a differential eqn for these conditions.

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

A solutes in bloodstream stream enter cells through a process called osmosis. Let $C=C(t)$ be the concentration inside a particular cell. The rate at which the concentration inside the cell is changing is proportional to the difference in the concentration of the solute in the bloodstream and in the cell. Suppose the concentration in the blood is constant $L $.

Find a differential eqn for $dC/dt$.

Your differential eqn will involve anew undetermined proportionality constant, what is it's sign?

Find all equilibrium solutions and their stability.

Ans:

I have worked out my differential eqn to be $dC/dt=k(L-C)$

I've determined my $k$ (prop const) is positive because if L>C then I expect my DE to be positive, which it is. Am I correct so far?

Also how do I answer the 3rd part?

Comment: OK so far, if L is greater than C you would expect net inflow to the cell so that the rate of change of C is positive. Use separation of variables to integrate your DE.

Comment: “if L>C then I expect my DE to be positive”.  I think you mean you expect $dC/dt$ to be positive.  As for (c), do you know how to find equilibrium solutions of homogeneous equations in general?

Comment: Finding equilibrium solutions means setting $\frac{dC}{dt}=0$. Thus, at equilibrium $L=C$.

Comment: Matthew, Yes thats what I meant. So k is positive? @Lovsovs Alright! Yeah I did know that but is that my only equilibrium? For stability, I notice that it's converging to $L=C $ from both sides but how do I prove it for any? Do I just choose arbitrary $a $ for above and below?